# How to `conda install ipython`?

Tags: python, conda

System: Ubuntu 14.04, python 2.7.6, pip 1.5.4 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7). I am trying to setup my packages by `conda` because of this table [here](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/_downloads/conda-pip-virtualenv-translator.html) in my system.
I did successfully

```
sudo -H pip install auxlib
sudo -H pip install conda
```

I do successfully `conda create -n my_root --clone=/usr`. I run `source activate my_root` but I get

```
bash: activate: No such file or directory
```

I still run `conda install ipython` but I get eventually

```
Error: Missing write permissions in: /usr
#
# You don't appear to have the necessary permissions to install packages
# into the install area '/usr'.
# However you can clone this environment into your home directory and
# then make changes to it.
# This may be done using the command:
#
# $ conda create -n my_root --clone=/usr
```

---

How can you run `conda install ipython`?

Comment: I think you need to create an environment and then activate it so that you don't require `sudo` privileges to install packages.

Comment: @edwinksl Yes, you are correct. I create there an environment but fail to activate the environment, which I do not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to run at least `conda install ipython` as root (sudo).

The same likely applies to the other commands.